# JavaFX 1 FXML File with Multiple Different Controllers?

Tags: controller, javafx, fxml

There are two different stages in my application that are help screens that use the same FXML file.  Rather than create 2 FXML files, I would like to use just one and have two controllers that call the same fxml.

The only problem is that the Controller is assigned in the FXML file.  So, is there a way to change the assigned controller with code in the Controller class itself?

I'd really like to avoid duplicating an FXML file just to change the Controller in each.  Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the `fx:controller=""` assignment from the `FXML` file and assign the controller via the `FXMLLoader` during the load.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Your.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(this);

try
{
    fxmlLoader.load();
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}
```

Check out the [Introduction to FXML section on custom components](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components).

Comment: Using this approach prevents you from using `@FXML` tags. You have to set them all manually, which can be umbersome when having nested views.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the FXML file multiple other fxml files can be referenced by the `<fx:include>` tag. Each fxml file can define their own controller with the `fx:controller` attribute.
Inside the `fx:controller` tag a type is given not an instance, so a custom [Controllerfactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) might be used when parsing it with the FXML loader.

The `setControllerFactor` function expects a `Callback` type, which is an interface with only one callable function: `call` which the factory uses. The function (called by the FXMLLoader class) expects to get a `Class` object as an input parameter and provides an instantiated object based on the type. Above Java8 lambdas can be used to provide the factory:

```java
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> controllerType) ->{
    if(controllerType == Controller.class){
        return new Controller();
    }
});
Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
```

The argument `controllerType` in the above code is the the type provided by the fxml `fx:controller` attribute, which is determined by the [Java Class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). When the Controllerfactory is called, nothing is instantiated yet, that's why even abstract classes can be given in the fxml. To achieve different behavior, inheritance can be used.

An example would be:

```java
class Controller{...}
class FirstController extends Controller{...}
class SecondController extends Controller{...}
```

And the factory can be used like so:

```java
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
final int[] instantiatedClasses  = {0};
loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> controllerType) ->{
    if(controllerType == Controller.class){
        if(0 == instantiatedClasses[0]){
            ++instantiatedClasses[0];
            return new FirstController();
        } else return new SecondController();
    }
});
Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
```

Please Note, that this way different arguments can also be supplied to the controller, so inheritance might be an overkill.
For example the primaryStage can be provided to the controller, e.g. for eliminating the need for different setters in the controllers.

```java
class Controller{
    public Controller(int behaviorParam){...}
}
```

```java
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
final int[] instantiatedClasses  = {-1}; /* so it would start at 0 */
loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> controllerType) ->{
    if(controllerType == Controller.class){
        ++instantiatedClasses[0]; 
        return new Controller(instantiatedClasses[0]);
    }
});
Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
```

The challenges of this method, however is that it is still not straightforward to differentiate between the different fxml instances of the same controller type. Counting the number of instantiated classes is one way that works, but it doesn't give much control, compared to anything identifier based.