# Using scene builder and multiple controllers

Tags: javafx, fxml

With my application growing, I'd like to create additional classes to handle the sql queries, the data validation, etc. Currently, the controller manages it all.

However, I have no idea how to go about creating different classes that can "talk" to the components in my controller class and with my .fxml file.

I attemped this: [JavaFX 1 FXML File with Multiple Different Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964832/javafx-1-fxml-file-with-multiple-different-controllers)

..and tried creating a new class to populate a table as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class DepartmentTable {

    private Connection conn;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Department> departmentTableView;// = new TableView<>(staffTypeList);
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Department, Integer> departmentIdCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Department, String> departmentNameCol;
    private ObservableList<Department> departmentList;

    public DepartmentTable(Connection aconn, FXMLLoader loader) {
        this.conn = aconn;
        this.fxmlLoader=loader;
        loadController();
        populateDepartmentTable();
    }

    private void loadController(){
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    }

    private void populateDepartmentTable() {

        departmentList = new DepartmentData(conn).getDepartmentList();

        /*Populate the Table with StaffType objects*/
        departmentIdCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Department, Integer>("departmentID"));
        departmentNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Department, String>("departmentName"));

        departmentTableView.setItems(departmentList);
    }
}
```

However, I get an invocationTargetException which is caused by a NullPointerException at

```
/*Populate the Table with StaffType objects*/
        departmentIdCol.setCellValueFactory(
```

So I am not sure what to do at this point.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more simple to create multiple FXML and Controller. 1 FXML = 1Controller.
And you can comunicate betweeen the different controller with no problems.

Look at this part [Nested Controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)